# vba call from excel to python code returns excel error waiting ole action

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, xlwings

I have a problem with a python code executed from Excel using  call from vba xlwing. Problem is that script takes a long time to execute the tasks (but it's normal due to amount of data).
after 90 secs excel shows a popup with error: excel is waiting for python complete ole action, and if click ok, after 10 secs message come back again. Is there any way to handle this error and fixed it? python code is running correctly, but it takes a long time to do all tasks.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display_alerts` to `False` on your `app` object. For example:

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
wb.app.display_alerts = False
```

See also related discussion: https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/120

Comment: this was very helpful. I had a working spreadsheet and realized a timeout issue was triggering this error. the above python code fixed the problem. Thank you Felix

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: read all data from excel into python, treat it, and create a new excel with the result, or overwrite the existing file. It will be much more smooth.